# Use the characteristic function of a geometric function to derive $E[X]=\frac{1}{p}$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, characteristic-functions, geometric-distribution

Suppose $X$ has geometric distribution $Geo(p)$, I want to use the characteristic function $\phi_{X}(t)=\frac{pe^{it}}{1-(1-p)e^{it}}$ to derive $E[X]=\frac{1}{p}$.

I tried $\phi_{X}(t)=E[e^{itx}]=\frac{pe^{it}}{1-(1-p)e^{it}}=\Sigma_{x=0}^{\infty}f_X(x)e^{itx}=\Sigma_{x=0}^{\infty}p(1-p)^{x-1}e^{itx}$ but got stuck from here.

Am I on the right track or is there another way to get $E[X]$ from $E[e^{itx}]$?

Comment: The characteristic/moment generating functions are useful because their derivatives are nicely related to the moments. Here, $\phi'(0) = i E[X]$.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac d {dt} \phi_X(t)=iEXe^{itX}$ and evaulating this at $t=0$ gives $iEX$. So calculate the left side using the formula  for $\phi_X(t)$; use quotient rule for differentiation.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. However, I did the differentiation and used the above formula but I got $E[X]=\frac{p^2+p-1}{p^2}$. I checked my work a few times and couldn't find out where I messed up. Is this solution somehow related to $E[X]=\frac{1}{p}$?

edit: found my mistake, I took the p out of the derivative first and I got the correct results, so maybe having p inside the derivative the whole time complicated the process